# How do I split a string in make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to take a parameter in my Makefile that consists of a host identifier in the form

```
host[:port]
```

where the colon and port are optional.  So all of the following are valid:

```
foo.example.com
ssl.example.com:443
localhost:5000
```

etc.

I want to split the string on the optional colon and assign the values to variables, so that `HOST` contains `foo.example.com`, `ssl.example.com`, `localhost`, etc., and `PORT` contains 80 (the default port), 443, and 500 respectively.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
# Retrieves a host part of the given string (without port).
# Param:
#   1. String to parse in form 'host[:port]'.
host = $(firstword $(subst :, ,$1))

# Returns a port (if any).
# If there is no port part in the string, returns the second argument
# (if specified).
# Param:
#   1. String to parse in form 'host[:port]'.
#   2. (optional) Fallback value.
port = $(or $(word 2,$(subst :, ,$1)),$(value 2))
```

Usage:

```
$(call host,foo.example.com) # foo.example.com
$(call port,foo.example.com,80) # 80

$(call host,ssl.example.com:443) # ssl.example.com
$(call port,ssl.example.com:443,80) # 443
```