# How to extract text from a particular point in string using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, cygwin

I want to break single string into two different strings using `sed`.

For eg:

```
STRING := folder1_test.abc_xxx

STRING1 := folder1_test

STRING2 := abc_xxx

or 

STRING := folderB_test folderA_test.yyyy_xx 

STRING1 := folderB_test folderA_test

STRING2 := yyyy_xx
```

So whatever is before dot(.) I want in first string and after dot(.) I want that thing in second string.

Specifically with `sed` command only. As I am using in makefile implementation.

Comment: would `cut -d.` be sufficient?

Comment: can you more specify how to use cut -d particularly for above case as i am new to linux .

Comment: what will be your expected output if input is something like : `STRING := folderC_test folderD_rd.zzzz_yy folderA_test.yyyy_xx`

Comment: @sat no it will not be like this there will be only one dot 
so whatever is before dot in  one string and after dot in second
**folderCV_test folderGHJ_test  floderA_test.yyy_xxx**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post I understand that you need this in a Makefile (and the syntax is confirming this). In that case this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8540718/3464942

For example:
`STRING1 := $(firstword $(subst ., ,$(STRING)))`
`STRING2 := $(or $(word 2,$(subst ., ,$(STRING))),$(value 2))`

Answer (score 0):

## One command line:

With `tr` cmd:

```
echo 'folderB_test folderA_test.yyyy_xx' | tr "." "\n"
# gives folderB_test folderA_test
#       yyyy_xx
```

With cut (set delimiter to . and display field 1 (-f1)):

```
echo 'folderB_test folderA_test.yyyy_xx' | cut -d. -f1
# gives folderB_test folderA_test
```

With cut (set delimiter to . and display field2 (-f2)):

```
echo 'folderB_test folderA_test.yyyy_xx' | cut -d. -f2
# gives yyyy_xx
```

## Store result in an array and read it:

```
#!/bin/bash

IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"

#With tr cmd:
arr=$(echo $IN | tr ";" "\n")

#With sed cmd:
arr=$(echo $IN | sed 's/;/\'$'\n/g')

for x in $arr
do
    echo "$x"
done
```

Gives:

```
bla@some.com
john@home.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
$ str='folder1_test.abc_xxx'
$ echo "${str%.*}"
folder1_test
$ echo "${str#*.}"
abc_xxx

$ str='folderB_test folderA_test.yyyy_xx'
$ echo "${str%.*}"
folderB_test folderA_test
$ echo "${str#*.}"
yyyy_xx
```

replace `echo` with variable assignment as per requirement

```
$ string='folderB_test folderA_test.yyyy_xx'
$ string1="${string%.*}"
$ echo "$string1"
folderB_test folderA_test
$ string2="${string#*.}"
$ echo "$string2"
yyyy_xx
```

**Note:** It is preferable to use lowercase for user defined variables

Answer (score 0):

I think it will answer your question.

`sed 's/\(^\(.*\)\.\(.*\)$\)/STRING  : \1\nSTRING 1: \2\nSTRING 2: \3/g'`

Ex:

> sed 's/(^(.*).(.*)$)/STRING  : \1\nSTRING 1: \2\nSTRING 2: \3/g'
>
> folderB_test folderA_test.yyyy_xx  //input
>
> STRING  : folderB_test folderA_test.yyyy_xx
>
> STRING 1: folderB_test folderA_test
>
> STRING 2: yyyy_xx